# String injection of Python3 command-line args

Tags: python, python-3.x, concatenation

New to Python, I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

env = sys.argv[1:]  # The name of the environment we're executing over ('Dev', 'Test', 'Prod', etc)

print('Executing against ' + env)
```

Above, the script should be invoked with an `env` argument that is then printed out to STDOUT.

Is there any more elegant way to inject the `env` variable into the string being printed (so I don't have that nasty-looking `+` concatenation going on)?

Comment: You could use `.format`

Comment: This would work the same if you replaced the "+" with a comma and removed the trailing space after "against". You could also use str.format as explained here: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_formatted_output.php

Comment: Note the answer on the linked question that recommends f-strings.  They're probably simplest way to format strings, but are only available in Python 3.6+ `f"Executing against {env}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
print('Executing against {}'.format(env))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `+` is that the second argument must be a string, otherwise an error is thrown. If that's not an issue, using `+` will work. However, there are other, usually more idiomatic ways:

1.) the print function can take multiple arguments, which get concatenated with a space:

`print('Executing against', env)`

2.) "old-style" interpolation:

`print('Executing against %s' % env)`

The right-hand side may also take multiple arguments in a tuple. So to protect against the possibility of the argument to be a tuple itself, you usually always put your variable in a tuple:

`print('Executing against %s' % (env,))`

3.) The more modern way is to use `.format` and its ecosystem (there's magic `__format__` methods and whatnot you usually don't need to know about but gives you great flexibility):

`print('Executing against {}'.format(env))`

4.) Python 3.6 and upwards: Syntactic sugar for `.format()`. You can now directly put variables, and even whole expressions inside the string by making it a format-string (prefix it with `f`):

`print(f'Executing against {env}')`